# How to implement manual click event on dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, delegates

i have a `mainbox` inside which some more boxes are dynamically generated.

```
// first time retrive
$.post("dataretrive.php", {
    }, function(data, status) {
        document.getElementById('mainbox').innerHTML = data;
        timer();
    });
```

then on click on these subboxes some i am implementing some functionality

```
$('.boxes-main').unbind('click').on('click', '.subbox', function(e){
    var value1 = $(this).attr('data');
    var value2 = $(this).attr('data2');
    var value3 = $(this).attr('data3');
    var value11 = $(this).attr('data4');
    var value12 = $(this).attr('data5');
    var value13 = $(this).attr('data6');
...... // some more functionality with these data which i think doesn't matter for this question for this question
    });
```

As i want to implement shortcuts to these `subbox` like when user press 1 it trigger a click event on that box. I also have ID's associated with that. like `box1 , box2, box3` and so on. and i am trying to put a click event of that box when key 1 is pressed.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.charCode == 49) {
$('#box1').click();
  }
});
```

I had also tried `trigger` function , `$("boxes-main #box1').click();` but nothing works because contents are dynamically generated. someone tell me please how to implement manual click event on dynamically generated element.

and don't get confused between `boxes-main` and `mainbox` both are class and id of same div element.

Comment: Please show an example of the dynamically generated elements' HTML. If you can select it you can trigger a click with `.click()`. If you can't select it, due to another problem, that may be the issue.

Comment: Also note: you should use `off` with `on` for consistency (not `unbind`). It may work but it is confusing to readers :)

Comment: Based on your comment, you are targeting the wrong element with your delegated event handler. Added explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> and don't get confused between boxes-main and mainbox both are class
>   and id of same div element.

It is not the click generation that is broken, but you are targeting the wrong ancestor in your delegated `click` event handler. Go higher up the ancestors to a non-changing element. `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer.

```
$(document).on('click', '.subbox', function(e){
```

### Notes:

- Don't mix `bind` with `on`. Use `off` instead
- You don't need `off`/`unbind` at all in this example